# ReactJS: What does “this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog);” mean in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying a React app made up by one main component: App.js (the main one) and three other external components: Dog.js, DogItem.js, AddDog.js The App contain a set of items (Dogs): Dog.js, made up of single dog elements, DogItem.js, and a form: AddDog.js to add a new item: dog. 
In the AddDog.js file, the only line I don't realize is: this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog); I have highlighted it below.

I'd like to underline that addDog in this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog);  is different from the name of the component AddDog.

---

Here's AddDog.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddDog extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newDog:{}
    }
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    categories: ['Web Design', 'Web Development', 'Mobile Development']
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    if(this.refs.name.value === '') {
      alert('Title is required');
    } else if (this.refs.image.value === '') {
        alert('Image link is required');
    } else if (this.refs.breed.value === '') {
          alert('Breed is required');
    } else {
      this.setState({newDog:{
        name: this.refs.name.value,
        breed: this.refs.breed.value,
        image: this.refs.image.value
      }}, function() {
        this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 id="addDog">Add Dog</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><br />
            <input id="dogName" type="text" ref="name" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Image</label><br />
            <input id="imageURL" type="text" ref="image" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Breed</label><br />
            <input id="dogBreed" type="text" ref="breed" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <br />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddDog;
```

---

Here's the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dogs from './components/Dogs';
import DogItem from './components/DogItem';
import AddDog from './components/AddDog';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dogs: []
    };
  }

  getDogs() {
    var defaultDogs = {dogs: [
      {
        name: 'Princess',
        breed: 'Corgi',
        image: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/51/ae/30/51ae30b78696b33a64661fa3ac205b3b.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'Riley',
        breed: 'Husky',
        image: 'http://portland.ohsohandy.com/images/uploads/93796/m/nice-and-sweet-siberian-husky-puppies-for-free-adoption.jpg'
      },
    ]}; 
    this.setState(defaultDogs);
  }

  componentWillMount() { // this soon display the two dogs before the render
    this.getDogs();  
  }

  handleAddDog(dog) {
    let dogs = this.state.dogs;
    dogs.push(dog);
    this.setState({dogs:dogs});
  }

  handleDeleteDog(name) {
    let dogs = this.state.dogs;
    let index = dogs.findIndex(x => x.name === name); // function (x) {return x.name === name} is like  x => x.name === name
    dogs.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({dogs:dogs});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Dogs dogs={this.state.dogs} onDelete={this.handleDeleteDog.bind(this)} />
        <AddDog addDog={this.handleAddDog.bind(this)} />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's Dog.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DogItem from './DogItem';

class Dogs extends Component {
    deleteDog(name) {
        this.props.onDelete(name);
    }

    render() {
        let dogItem;
        if (this.props.dogs) {
            dogItem = this.props.dogs.map(dog => {
                return (
                    <DogItem onDelete={this.deleteDog.bind(this)} key={dog.name} dog={dog} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <div className="Dogs">
                <h1>Good Dogs</h1>
                {dogItem}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dogs;
```

Here's DogItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DogItem extends Component {
  deleteDog(name) {
    this.props.onDelete(name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="Dog">
        <img src={this.props.dog.image} href={this.props.dog.image} role="presentation"  width="100" height="100"></img>
        <br></br>
        <strong>{this.props.dog.name}</strong>: {this.props.dog.breed} <a href="#" onClick={this.deleteDog.bind(this, this.props.dog.name)}>X</a>
        <br></br>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default DogItem;
```

Comment: That is a callback function which will be passed in to it by a parent component. The purpose is to notify that parent component that a dog was just added. Personally i'd probably name the prop something different like "onDogAdded", but that's just me.

Comment: @Nicholas may you add more details pls?

Comment: What more details could there be? He told you exactly what it's for... that's how you pass state up the chain in React. I'd say it's an anti pattern to pass a component's state up (compared to letting the parent manage it), but whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a callback function from the parent component. (In this case App.js)
It's used to add the new dog into the dogs array in the App's state.

So when you the function `this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog)` is called, it's calling the function that has been passed in as a prop by the parent component
(`<AddDog addDog={this.handleAddDog.bind(this)} />` in App.js)

Which means when you call `this.props.addDog(this.state.newDog)`,
`this.handleAddDog()` gets called in the App.js component with the new Dog Object as the argument (`this.handleAddDog(this.state.newDog)` with "this.state" refering to the state of the AddDog Component)

I hope that was detailed and clear enough ;)